# jhipster generated application failed to run on netbeans

Tags: node.js, maven, netbeans, yeoman, jhipster

I created an application using hipster and then I opened the generated maven project over netbeans and run it. 
I got this error :

> Failed to execute goal com.github.trecloux:yeoman-maven-plugin:0.4:build (run-grunt) on project cabinet-medical: Error during : node --version: Cannot run program "node" (in directory "/Users/retina/Dropbox/QEMWEB/WORK/PROJETS/LOGICIELS/hispter/cabinet_hipster_generate"): error=2, No such file or directory -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu, you might run into this issue, if you have installed Node.js via [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) and not via a global system package.

A possible workaround based on [another example](http://www.marcominetti.net/personal/blog/2015/09/install-system-wide-node-js-with-nvm-the-painless-way) to create an executable file named as `/usr/local/bin/node`, which loads the NVM environment first with the following content:

```
 #\!/bin/bash
 export NVM_DIR="/home/USER/.nvm"
 [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
 node $@
```

Replace NVM_DIR with the path of your NVM installation and make the file executable for example with `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/node`.